# Auto select value of dropdown

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

How can I auto select a field in dropdown.

Say if someone goes to `www.xyx/form/?abc`
Some value gets selected in the dropdown,

Or if someone goes to `www.xyx/form/?def`
Some other value gets selected in the dropdown.

I am comfortable with JS and php.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

assuming `example.com/?sel=xxx`

```
<?php
  $sel = $_GET['sel'];

?>
<select ...>
  <option val="xxx" <?php if($sel==='xxx') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Option XXX</option>
  <option val="yyy" <?php if($sel==='yyy') echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Option YYY</option>
</select>
```

No Javascript needed.

Comment: You need 'selected' not 'checked' for 'options'

Comment: I think `'checked="checked"'` should be `'selected="selected"'` (assuming XHTML), or just `'selected'` (assuming HTML)

Comment: I'm not sure about html5, but I just use the always bulletproof method (s="s")

Comment: Also the question uses 'abc' as a key and not a value

Comment: I just assumed that he will not use arguments without key [because that's what it is, not key without value, I guess] in the end.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP**

```
<select name="select">
 <option value="abc"<?php ($_GET['select'] == 'abc'? echo 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>ABC</option>
 <option value="def"<?php ($_GET['select'] == 'def'? echo 'selected="selected"' : ''); ?>>DEF</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing with an answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="abc" <?php echo isset($_GET['abc']) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>abc</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, so what will you do when you have 100s of items in the Options list? The other ideas wont look so great then.

Then you will need to just simply write 1 line of code at the end of select tag:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['env_foil_color'])) echo "<script>document.getElementById('env_foil_color').value='{$_POST['env_foil_color']}';</script>"; ?>
```

where, 'env_foil_color' is the select tag's ID and Name both